# How to map the integer values in a column in a pandas datfarme to random n-digit numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[111, 7,8], [409,6,4], [333, 9,0],[111,3,2],[111,0,0], [409,7,0]], columns=['A','B','C'])
df
     A  B  C
0  111  7  8
1  409  6  4
2  333  9  0
3  111  3  2
4  111  0  0
5  409  7  0
```

How to map column A to 10-digit random integers such that the same value in columns A (such as 111) has the same 10-digit random integer in the new array. For example, I want something like this

```
     A         B  C
0  8765479834  7  8
1  7653780954  6  4
2  9400211346  9  0
3  8765479834  3  2
4  8765479834  0  0
5  7653780954  7  0
```

Thank you!

Comment: what's the correlation between the numbers in the old A column and the new one?

Comment: There is no correlation between them. Just a random mapping is fine as long as the same random number is assign for the same number in the old data frame. For example, in the old data frame the columns A is 111 for rows 0, 3 and 4. A for the rows 0, 3, 4 in the new data frame is all 8765479834.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way via `hashlib`:

```
import hashlib
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda s: int(hashlib.sha1(str(s).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), 16) % (10 ** 8))
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
          A  B  C
0  22445762  7  8
1  63857454  6  4
2  61248669  9  0
3  22445762  3  2
4  22445762  0  0
5  63857454  7  0
```

*NOTE:* If you want values of random length you can also use:

```
df['A'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df['A'], index =False)
```

Comment: Should be 10**10.  Great answer.

Comment: This is not random mapping as required by OP. If the goal is anonymization this is a flaw.

Comment: @buran I still believe this is what OP wants. I'll wait for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and numpy

```
# find unique values in A
unique = df['A'].unique()
# use numpy to generate a random int
data = np.random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999, len(unique))
# zip the random int with your unique values and map to col A
df['A'] = df['A'].map(dict(zip(unique, data)))

            A  B  C
0  8059444826  7  8
1  2465745168  6  4
2  8408792865  9  0
3  8059444826  3  2
4  8059444826  0  0
5  2465745168  7  0
```